# How to render only visible object without using layering or doing some cumbersome steps?

Tags: interface

When i hide object how to automatically make them invisible in rendering ? i just want to do simple fast test every object i want to inspect. Moving object manually to layer is not fast workflow. Also manually turn off the camera icon in outliner will be to slow. Is there any setting that when i hide object , it also turn off visibility in rendering automatically ?

I just want to do fast on/off rendering some part of my model without have to deal with layering.

Answer (score 1):

To render only some objects in viewport you can just go to the local view of the object by press <kbd>/</kbd>. To hide objects in render mode, just select the objects to be shown in the render or select the objects to be hidden from the render and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to invert the selection (remember that objects to be hidden should not be selected) and then press <kbd>W</kbd> then select *Restrict render unselected*. Thus any unselected objects wont be rendered. To remove this, press <kbd>W</kbd> and press *Clear all restrict render*.

Comment: Dear Ashok, thank you for contributing. For future reference: Keyboard shortcuts are best represented with the <kbd></kbd> tags.